# Вывести стек исключений

Tags: java, исключения

Нужно вывести стек исключений, например:

```
throw new Exception("ABC", new RuntimeException("DEF", new IllegalAccessException("GHI")));
```

Желаемый вывод:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: GHI

java.lang.RuntimeException: DEF

java.lang.Exception: ABC
```

Как можно реализовать это наиболее эффективным путём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса Throwable есть метод getCause() он возвращает ввложеное исключение, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause() можно рекурсивно перебрать и вывести

Comment: Помогло ваше решение, т.к. нужно было перехватить unchecked-exception

Answer (score 2):

```
...
catch(Exception exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: данный способ выводит только конкретное исключение. Мне нужно, чтобы выводило иерархию исключения

Comment: Само название говорит о том, что распечатывается не одну исключение, а вся _трасса_. И [в документации пишут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) "Prints this throwable **and its backtrace** to the standard error stream."  Наконец, [я проверил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CBFt.png).

Comment: Выводит не то, что мне нужно. В примере всё написано